# Migration from mfc to Qt in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt, mfc, migration, walkthrough

I want to replace my MFC Code with Qt. I found this website http://doc.qt.digia.com/solutions/4/qtwinmigrate/winmigrate-walkthrough.html and they say that it works with VS6. 
My question is now if I can use this site as a guideline for the replacement with Visual Studio 2010 to and if anyone has experience with Walkthrough on Visual Studio 6?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, this side looks really outdated. What is your goal? You want to only use Qt? How big is the UI Part of your Application?

Comment: The winmigrate module has been dead for longer than most people write code. It has been abandoned when VS6 was all the rage. Unless you have a very good reason to move to Qt (targeting multiple platforms would be one such reason), I would strongly advice you to stick with MFC. MFC GUIs are generally more robust, standards compliant, and user friendly.

Comment: @IInspectable: But Qt does a great job integrating in Windows. You can even preview your UI in different Windows Styles. And if the software tries to reach a huge group of customers, targeting multiple platforms is the right choice.

Comment: The UI Part is not the biggest part of the application, but if I had to rewrite it, it would take a bit of time. 
The problem is I havn't written the MFC Code and now i have to change quite a bit. It's the first time that i have something to do with UI. So I read that Qt is much more comfortable than MFC.

Comment: Using winmigrate requires that you know MFC **and** Qt. You will not understand MFC unless you understand the Windows API. Your options are: 1.) Learn the Windows API and MFC, and 2.) Learn the Windows API, MFC, and Qt.

Comment: @IInspectable "MFC GUIs are generally more robust, standards compliant, and user friendly." This statement is just plain wrong. These characteristics depend on the developers who wrote the application. To reach "robust, standard compliant, and user friendly" in a MFC application more effort is needed than with Qt.

Comment: @ChrisInked: The point is, that you **can** reach a state, where a GUI is *robust, standards compliant and user friendly* with MFC. This is not possible with Qt, regardless of the amount of effort you put into it, for technical reasons. Qt is broken at the core, implementing its message handling based on invalid assumptions. For example, it doesn't honor the fact that [replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/12/06/10375039.aspx).