# Add QT widgets to Windows API GUI

Tags: qt, user-interface, winapi, hwnd

How can I add a QT widget to an existing GUI which created by Windows API.
I have its HWND.
If it is not possible, is there any way for nesting them?

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24140876/migration-from-mfc-to-qt-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: @SaZ: How does *winmigrate* allow you to host a Qt widget inside a native dialog?

Comment: @IInspectable look at `QWinWidget` class. It accepts parent HWND.